# WAS 7 Network Deploymen - Servers doesn't start automatically after abnormal shutdown?

Tags: java, websphere, application-server, cluster-computing

I've websphere application server 7 network deployment, and am facing a very strange issue, I've three nodes with three servers, and one deployment manager for the three nodes, if one of the servers stopped abnormally, 
it shows a question mark in the deployment manager, and when it come back up, the server service is started, but the deployment manager shows it as stopped, and I have to start it from the deployment manager, 
if I stopped the server service manually its status is also a question mark at the deployment manager, but when I started the service again manually, now it's shown as started in the deployment manager,

I can't find any explanation for this strange behavior, your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, there's settings for this part, you can reach it from here:

> To view this administrative console page, click Servers > Server Types
>
> > WebSphere application servers > server_name. Then, under Server Infrastructure, click Java and process management > Monitoring policy.

and then the one corresponding to this behavior is found here: Node Restart State

> ```
> If this property is set to STOPPED, node agent does not start the server.
> If this property is set to RUNNING, the node agent always starts the server.
> If this property is set to PREVIOUS, the node agent starts the server only if the server was running when the node agent stopped.
> ```
>
> Note: Changes you make to the node restart state become effective
>   after the node is synchronized. At the next NodeAgent restart (after
>   the synch), the node restart state will be honored.

and here's a full link for this topic: [Monitoring Policy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rmonitorpol.html)